# How can i append a space in each side of a string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, append

i have a NSString object named as myString.i need to append a space in each side of my string.
can any one tell me the good way to do it?

Comment: got it ...stringByAppendingString

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", myString];
```

Comment: you beat me by 44 seconds..haha

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @" %@ ", myString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you can do it in this way.

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@" %@ ",str];
```

Comment: Note that this string isn’t autoreleased, so you will need to release it manually later.